# MySQL Transofrming table to matrix without null values

Tags: mysql, sql, matrix, pivot-table

I have a table with countries and translations in diferent languages, something like this (maybe some data could be wrong, but are only sample values):

```
lanId, countryId, name, translation
1,        1,      Spain,  Spain
1,        2,      France, France
1,        3,      Italy,  Italy
2,        1,      Spain,  España
2,        2,      France, Francia
2,        3,      Italy,  Italia
3,        1,      Spain,  Espagne
3,        2,      France, France
3,        3,      Italy,  Italie
```

What I need to get is a matrix showing one column for language, similar to this:

```
countryId, countryName, es,     fr,
1,           spain,    españa,  espagne
2,           france,   francia, france
3,           italy,    italia,  italie
```

I've tried using the CASE sentence:

```
SELECT countryId, 
case WHEN idLan =1 THEN translation  end as en,
case WHEN idLan =2 THEN translation END as es, 
case WHEN idLan =3 THEN translation END as fr,
FROM translations
```

But I get a lot of NULLs in each column, like this:

```
countryId, en,    es,     fr
1,       spain,  NULL,    NULL
2,       france, NULL,    NULL
3,       Italy,  NULL,    NULL
1,       NULL,   españa,  NULL
2,       NULL,   francia, NULL
3,       NULL,   italia,  NULL...
```

How could I get a matrix like this, but avoiding the null values?

```
countryId, en,    es,       fr
1,       spain,  españa,   espagne
2,       france, francia,  france
3,       Italy,  italia,   italie
```

Tanks.

Comment: You need a GROUP BY too.

Comment: Thanks. The key was grouping by countryId and name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following pivot query:

```
SELECT
    countryId,
    name,
    MAX(CASE WHEN lanId = 1 THEN translation END) AS en,
    MAX(CASE WHEN lanId = 2 THEN translation END) AS es,
    MAX(CASE WHEN lanId = 3 THEN translation END) AS fr
FROM translations
GROUP BY
    countryId,
    name
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Answer (score 1):

You need to group by the countryId:

```
SELECT countryId, 
case WHEN lanId = 1 THEN translation END as en,
case WHEN lanId = 2 THEN translation END as es, 
case WHEN lanId = 3 THEN translation END as fr
FROM translations
GROUP BY countryId
```